# Grails, combine fixed criteria with dynamic list of criterias

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I am doing an application that filters some log messages. The log messages belongs to a host, that belongs to a location. The controller allows to filter by text, host and some other parameters, and I need to add some dynamically generated closures to the criteria. With some code, this will be clarified; I have this in the Config.groovy (this closure is not fixed, this should be an external file dynamic reloaded when changed, and editable by the administrator):

```
pruebaclos = {
    host {
        location {
            ilike("slug", "%grs%")
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the controller, I have this:

```
// Hosts
List<Host> hosts = []
params.list("host_id")?.each { String hostIdStr ->
    if ( hostIdStr.isLong() ) {
        Long hostId = hostIdStr.toLong()
        Host host = Host.get(hostId)
        if ( host ) {
            hosts << host
        }
        else {
            // Not found
        }
    }
    else {
        // Id not valid
    }
}


// generated externally....
def additionalFilters = []
additionalFilters << grailsApplication.config.pruebaclos

def results = HostLogMessage.createCriteria().list (max: params.long("max"), offset: params.long("offset")) {

    and {

        if (hosts) {
            or {
                hosts.each { Host currentHost ->
                    eq("host", currentHost)
                }
            }
        }

        if ( params.user ) {
            ilike("user", "%${ params.user }%")
        }
        if ( params.facility ) {
            ilike("facility", "%${ params.facility }%")
        }
        if ( params.severity ) {
            ilike("severity", "%${ params.severity }%")
        }
        if ( params.message ) {
            ilike("message", "%${ params.message }%")
        }
    }

    or {
        additionalFilters.each {
            it.delegate = delegate
            it()
        }
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

```
could not resolve property: slug of: XXXXXX.HostLogMessage
```

If i put the same closure in the controller itself, I don't get any error and the closure is applied:

```
def myClos = {
    host {
        location {
            ilike("slug", "%cabu%")
        }
    }
}

def additionalFilters = []
additionalFilters << myClos
```

Any idea wht I get the error if I put the closure in the config file?

These are the main domain classes related (rubbish removed):

```
class Location {
    def configurationService
    static hasMany = [ 
        hosts: Host
    ]
    Location parent
    String slug
    String name
}

class Host {
    static hasMany = [ messages: HostLogMessage ]
    Location location
    String name
}

class HostLogMessage {
    static belongsTo = [ host: Host ]
    DateTime dateTime
    String user
    String facility
    String severity
    String message
}
```

Comment: what class do the elements of `additionalFilters` and the `delegate` have?

Comment: additionalFilters is a list of closures, that should be added to the criteria. I don't know exactly what 'delegate' is, I have seen that in many examples using reused-closures for criterias...

Comment: do `additionalFilters.each {
            it.delegate = delegate
            println "$it -> $delegate"
            it()
        }`

Comment: I think there is not much information... `Config$_run_closure5 -> com.github.okelet.mortero.grails.controller.LogController$_index_closure2_closure5`

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the catch is.. 
If you define a closure in the `Config.groovy`, it gets processed by a `config-builder` and is transformed on the way.

To avoid it, you shall define the closure explicitly:

```
def closure = {->
  host {
    location {
        ilike("slug", "%grs%")
    }
  }
}

pruebaclos = closure
```

or as a list:

```
pruebaclos = [ 
  {->
    host {
      location {
        ilike("slug", "%grs%")
      }
    }
  },

  {-> 
   //
  }
]
```

UPDATE:

looks like the direction of your nesting closures in criteria is wrong and 1 inner closure is missing.

instead of:

```
def closure = {->
  host {
    location {
        ilike("slug", "%grs%")
    }
  }
}
```

it should be the other way around + `messages` block:

```
def closure = {->
  location {
    host {
      messages{
        ilike("slug", "%grs%")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi injecteer, thak you very much, but this doesn't work... I get the same error.

Comment: post your domain classes (and ommit not-essential details)

Comment: nope, it doesn't work (it throws the same error `could not resolve property: slug of: xxxxx.HostLogMessage`), perhaps i haven't explained very well... I am applying the closure to a criteria for a HostLogMessage, so in the closure i must specify that the slug of the location of the host of the message (the criteria itself) must contain the text "grs". The same criteria defined in the own controller works fine, so it must be something related to the configuration file.